# compilation error in java "stray '@' in program"

Tags: java

i am trying to submit a java program in [codechef](http://www.codechef.com). I successfully compiled it and ran it using netbeans. But when i submit the code by uploading the corresponding .java file... it comes up like this...

`prog.cpp:41: error: stray '@' in program prog.cpp:4: error: 'import' does not name a type prog.cpp:7: error: expected unqualified-id before 'public'`

my java program starts like this....

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

`public class jewels{
    static int CNT=0;
    static String q,qq;`

and so on....

@Jon Skeet... u were ... I got the error... Sorry for that.. I was submitting it as a C++ file.
but now i am getting the new one...

`Main.java:7: class jewels is public, should be declared in a file named jewels.java public class jewels{ ^ 1 error`

although i uploaded the jewels.java file...
please help...

Comment: Where did you see this error? On some place on  the chodechef? May be you should post this issue to team of codechef.

Comment: I find the references to `prog.cpp` somewhat alarming here. Are you sure you've said it's Java code?

Comment: thanks.. i wil do that... :) .But is there any mistake with the starting code of my program??..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CodeChef requires that your main class in Java be called `Main`. See their [FAQ](http://www.codechef.com/wiki/faq#Why_do_I_get_a_compile_error).

Comment: Thank you all of you for ur help... Next time i will investigate deeply and then ask the question....

Answer (score 2):

`java.util.Scanner` is new in Java 1.5.  Maybe codechef's checking program requires the use of Java 1.4?

I don't know Netbeans very well, but in Eclipse you can specify the "Compiler complicance level" in the Preferences (under Java|Compiler).  Probably Netbeans also allows this. You could set the "Compiler complicance level" to 1.4 and try to recompile your program.

> Should i write any package name.

I don't think so, the [FAQ](http://www.codechef.com/wiki/faq#Why_do_I_get_a_compile_error) advises not to use packages.